# how definition the real numbers system in algebraic structure?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

I know that :

> An **algebraic structure** is a totally ordered set, whose elements are
>
> - sets $S_i$,
> - (finitary) operations $O_j$ over these sets,
> - relations $R_k$ between these sets.

Now  how  definition the real numbers system in algebraic structure ?

Comment: Your sets $S_i$ would be singletons $\{x\} \forall x \in \Bbb{R}$. Finitary operations are whatever operations you wish to imbue the set with, in this case, all the field operations.

I don't think there is any such definition of what does and doesn't constitute an algebraic structure. Almost anything we study in abstract algebra, is a structure of some sort. [This link](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Algebraic_system) may provide more insight.

Answer (score 1):

We need to squeeze

> $\Bbb R$ is a complete ordered field

into that pattern. So we would take $S_1=\Bbb R$, $O_1=+$, $O_2=\cdot$, $R_1={<}$ (alternatively, one can use the 1-ary relation "is positive"). That we have a field is experssed as a handfull of first-order axioms involving $O_1$ and $O_2$. That this is an ordered field is expressed as another handfull of first-order axioms involving $O_1,O_2,R_1$.

Completeness is a different story, though: This requires a second-order axiom or an $\infty$-ary relation. Or you add another set $S_2=\mathcal P(\Bbb R)$, but then you'd only push the goal to expressing that $S_2$ is the power set of $S_1$ ...

Comment: Now how ?$O_3=- ,O_4=()^{-1},.....$